# Firebase Functions Database 'child_added' Only Returning 1st Child (out of many children)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to return 
`{"length": "2","height": "4"},{"length": "1.5","height": "6"},{"length": "3","height": "5.5"},{"length": "2","height": "3.2"}` from the following setup in my RTDB. **What am I forgetting to include?**

```
{
    "widgets": {
        "widget01": {
            "length": "2",
            "height": "4"
        },
        "widget02": {
            "length": "1.5",
            "height": "6"
        },
        "widget03": {
            "length": "3",
            "height": "5.5"
        },
        "widget04": {
            "length": "7",
            "height": "3.2"
        }
    }
}
```

My function is...

```
exports.widgets = functions.database.ref().onUpdate(event => {
    admin.database().ref('/widget').once('child_added', snapshot =>{
      let data = snapshot.val()
      console.log(data)
      return ({data})
    });
});
```

But this is only returning `{"length": "2","height": "4"}` and not every child within "widget[i]". I thought...

> ...child_added is triggered once **for each** existing child...

*PS. Instead of `child_added` I did try to use `value`. However I couldn't figure out how to reference "widget[i]" within `.child()` since it is dynamic.*

```
exports.widgets = functions.database.ref().onUpdate(event => {    
    admin.database().ref('/widgets').child(<<how to structure?>>).once('value', snapshot =>{
        let data = snapshot.val()
        console.log(data)
        return ({data})
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling `once('child_added'`, your callback will only be triggered once: for the first child in the location you attach the listener to.

If you need all children in Cloud Functions, you should indeed use `once('value'`, which gives all matching child nodes in the snapshot at once. You then loop over those children with `snapshot.forEach()`:

```
exports.widgets = functions.database.ref().onUpdate(event => {    
    admin.database().ref('/widgets').once('value', snapshot =>{
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            let data = child.val()
            console.log(data)
            //return ({data})
        });
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to return though. Since there can be multiple children, what child do you want to return?

Comment: you're a lifesaver. I've been trying to figure this out longer than I'd like to admit. I actually wanted to return all of the children. I tweaked it a bit more based on my needs which now reads: `[ [ 2, 4 ], [ 1.5, 6 ] ]`.